# Ubuntu - can't edit / write files folders which were copied from another server through ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions

I used this command to copy a folder with containing files to another server:

```
scp -r root@89.22.122.xxx:/var/www/vhosts/bla1.blaaaa.com/httpdocs/videos/ /var/www/vhosts/bla2.blaaaa.com/httpdocs/videos/
```

it worked, but now I can't write new files into `/var/www/vhosts/bla2.blaaaa.com/httpdocs/videos/` nor delete or edit existing files inside of it.

Why and how to fix this??

Comment: What user are you when attempting to write new files (`whoami`), and what are the permissions on the videos directory (`ls -lad /var/www/vhosts/bla2.blaaaa.com/httpdocs/videos/`)?

Comment: It says: drwxr-xr-x 102 root root 4096 Jan 27 15:30

Comment: I tried to write/edit/delete files inside that folder over PHP and also FTP, both doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory you're trying to create new files in is owned by the user `root` and the group `root`. If you are authenticating to FTP as anything other than `root` you will not be able to write to that directory. Inside PHP, you are most likely trying to write as the `apache` user (the user running the Apache web server), which again is not `root` so it won't work. You probably want to change the ownership of that directory (and all directories and files below it) to the user you're using to FTP in.

Comment: Finally thanks!